# Class 'Vendor\PackageName\ClassName' not found for newly created Laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.5

I've a problem running my newly created Laravel package which please check out [https://github.com/Younesi/laravel-aparat](https://github.com/Younesi/laravel-aparat/)

I can download it via Composer with no problem and  it's auto-discovered via Laravel but when I try to use it, It gives me the following error of not finding class.

> Class 'Younesi\LaravelAparat\Aparat' not found

My service Provider code is like:

```
/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('aparat', function ($app) {
        return new Aparat;
    });

}

/**
 * Get the services provided by the provider.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function provides()
{
    return array('aparat');
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: put this use Aparat  in top of your file

Comment: @GauravGupta Adding 'use Younesi\LaravelAparat\Aparat;' Does not help

Comment: did you provide it's address to app.php in config

Comment: @GauravGupta In Laravel 5.5  packages can be auto-discover meaning no need for adding manually

Comment: there is one more theory your package has different class name check that

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the package it's working fine, in `composer.json` of that package there is:

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Younesi\\laravelAparat\\": "src"
    }
  },
```

Notice that `laravel` is not with capital letter here, so in your code you should import rather this way:

```
use Younesi\laravelAparat\Aparat;
```

instead of:

```
use Younesi\LaravelAparat\Aparat;
```

I also see that you are author of this package, so I would recommend using standard conversion (namespace starting with capital letter) instead of current namespace.

Looking further at package code, I also see that in service provider there is:

```
namespace Younesi\LaravelAparat;
```

namespace so it's nothing weird it won't work if you autoload it with lower-case letter and have namespace with upper-case letter

Answer (score 0):

There were some cases with registration problem, cache issues, etc. Try one of these solutions:

- register your provider (in main composer.json, then in config/app.php [provider & alias] ), then run `composer dump-autoload`
- make sure you have initiated your package : go to the folder, then `composer init`
- try `php artisan config:cache` or delete everything in `bootstrap/cache/`